# Problem with thread about startup

Tags: discussion, site-rec

I searched for this topic and found this post here : [How to start a Software Company](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57380/how-to-start-a-software-company)

But several times people refer to a web site called answers.onstartups.com which doesn't exist. Can someone point to a new source of information about starting a software company or perhaps fix the broken links?

Comment: answers.onstartups.com is just a bad link.  You want http://onstartups.com

Comment: Answers.onstartups.com used to be an SE site that kind of flopped. Onstartups.com isn't managed by Stack Exchange (and some things still point there and haven't been fixed (onstartups can map domain queries to another site which doesn't give a 404 page)). The closest thing to the answers.onstartups.com site is hub.onstartups.com (their Q&A clone - not stack exchange though).  There is also http://startups.stackexchange.com/ which is a stack exchange site.

Answer (score 4):

There's a bit of history around on startups.com and Stack Exchange.

Answers.onstartups.com was originally a Stack Exchange 1.0 community and was relaunched through area 51. After a rather long time, [the proposal was closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) for [various reasons](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/site-on-startups-is-closed-what-to-do-now).

There are a few posts that have answers.onstartups.com links (as of this writing, 23 found via [this search](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*.onstartups.com)) that should be cleaned up... (I think I got most of them though there may be some residual cleanup to do... 90% of them were links to the same post by Joel again and again).  Admittedly, that might take a bit of work to sleuth through http://www.brightjourney.com/ to find the corresponding post (assuming they grab the data dump - their Q&A clone doesn't use post IDs... they did grab the data dump, but not everything is there, they might have deleted some posts since then).

Onstartups.com still exists at http://onstartups.com and while they're pointing to a broken link for answers.onstartups.com themselves (SE doesn't own the onstartups.com domain).

As a note, the relaunch was relaunched again as http://startups.stackexchange.com and is still there if one is looking for content.